# How to prevent OpenLayers from applying pixel hinting?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-5

I am using OpenLayers 5.3.0 and I found that it applies pixel hinting to the styles. Two concentric circles are aren't perfectly centered.

This is the code for the style to render a specific feature:

```
style = [
            new Style({
                image: new Circle({
                    radius: orangeRadius,
                    fill: new Fill({
                        color: '#f4b04a'
                    }),
                    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],

                }),
            })
            , new Style({
                image: new Circle({
                    radius: greenRadius,
                    stroke: new Stroke({
                        color: '#48bfa5'
                        , width: 3
                    }),
                    anchor: [0.5, 0.5],

                }),
            })
        ];
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

How can I disable pixel hinting?

Thanks you!

Comment: Brother any JS fiddle link

Comment: Snapping to pixel is now the default, see the update notes for v5.2.0 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md

Comment: I created a working example. The problem arises with fractional radius values: https://codesandbox.io/s/347q71q77q

Comment: For now I fixed by adding `Math.round()` to the final radius of the circles. Thanks for pointing to the snap issue.